# How to perform Matrix multiplication with conditions in python?

Tags: python, pandas, matrix-multiplication

I am using matrix multiplication on a dataframe and its transpose with `df@df.T`

So if I have a df which looks like: (below 1 indicates that the object has the property whereas 0 indicates not having it):

```
Object Property1 Property2 Property3
A      1         1         1
B      0         1         1
C      1         0         0
```

Using df@df.T gives me:

```
   A  B  C
A  3  2  1  
B  2  2  0
C  1  0  1
```

This can be thought of a matrix showing how many properties each object has in common with another.

I now want to modify the problem where, instead of a binary indication of whether an object has a property, the properties column show levels of that property. So the new df looks like: (below the values 1,2,3 of properties shows its level. But 0 indicates not having the property)

```
Object Property1 Property2 Property3
A      3         2         1
B      0         2         3
C      2         0         0
```

I want to apply matrix multiplication, but with an altered definition of 'common' properties. Two objects will only have a common property if the levels of a property is within +-1 range of the other property.

Below is what the result will look like:

```
   A  B  C
A  3  1  1  
B  1  2  0
C  1  0  1
```

Note that the number of properties common between A and B have changed from 2 to 1. This is because property 3 between A and B is not within +-1 level. Also, 0 still means that the object does not have the property, so A and C still have 1 property in common (with property 3 for C being 0).

How can I achieve this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by modifying matrix multiplication for two DataFrames

**Code**

```
# DataFrame Matrix Multiplication
# i.e. equivalent to df1@df2
def df_multiply(df_a, df_b):
  '''
     Matrix multiplication of values in two DataFrames
     Returns a DataFrame whose index and column are
     from the df_a 
  '''
  a = df_a.values
  b = df_b.values
  zip_b = zip(*b)
  zip_b = list(zip_b)
  zip_b = b
  result = [[sum(ele_a*ele_b for ele_a, ele_b in zip(row_a, col_b)) 
             for col_b in zip_b] for row_a in a]

  return pd.DataFrame(data=result, index=df_a.index, columns=df_a.index)

# Modify df_multiply for desired result
def df_multiply_modified(df_a, df_b):
  '''
         Modified Matrix multiplication of values in two DataFrames to create desired result
         Returns a DataFrame whose index and
         column are from the df_a
  '''
  a = df_a.values
  b = df_b.values
  zip_b = zip(*b)
  zip_b = list(zip_b)
  
  # sum 1 when difference <= 1 and 
  # values are non-zero
  # i.e. ele_a and ele_b and abs(ele_a-ele_b) <=1
  result = [[sum(1 if ele_a and ele_b and abs(ele_a-ele_b) <=1 else 0 for ele_a, ele_b in zip(row_a, col_b)) 
             for col_b in zip_b] for row_a in a]

  return pd.DataFrame(data=result, index=df_a.index, columns=df_a.index)
```

**Usage**

*Original Multiplication*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Object':['A', 'B', 'C'],
                  'Property1':[1, 0, 1],
                  'Property2':[1, 1, 0],
                  'Property3':[1, 1, 0]})

df.set_index('Object', inplace = True)
print(df_multiply(df, df.T)
# Output (same as df@df.T):
Object  A  B  C
Object         
A       3  2  1
B       2  2  0
C       1  0  1
```

*Modified Multiplication*

```
# Use df_multiply_modified
df = pd.DataFrame({'Object':['A', 'B', 'C'],
                  'Property1':[3, 0, 2],
                  'Property2':[2, 2, 0],
                  'Property3':[1, 3, 0]})
df.set_index('Object', inplace = True)
print(df_multiply_modified(df, df.T)
# Output (same as desired)
Object  A  B  C
Object         
A       3  1  1
B       1  2  0
C       1  0  1
```

Comment: Thanks. The code for 'Modified Multiplication' works as you show but the output when running 'Original Multiplication' is different from what you show. Nevertheless, the modified multiplication code runs fine so it answers the question.

Comment: @TheloniousMonk--you mention the original is different.  Is  your DataFrame the same as what I show (including the index column i.e. using set_index) or is it different?  If so, how is it generated?

Comment: I ran your code where you define functions and the block 'Original Multiplication'. The output seems to be different

Comment: @TheloniousMonk--couldl you add code to you post that would allow me to create the data you show in your example (i.e. this is normally recommended for posts).  Then,  I can see the difference you're mentioning.